# cygwin compiler cannot find shell32

Tags: c, cygwin

I just downloaded Cygwin64 and whenever I try to compile my C code with gcc, I'm getting these errors:

```
Andre@ResidentEvil /cygdrive/c/Users/Andre/Desktop/Code
$ gcc pingpipe.c -o pingpipe
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

All the errors said "32" so I made an uneducated assumption that the error might be trying to find 32 files when I was using cygwin64. In the end I tried fixing it by linking my system path variable to the w32api in cygwin... no luck (unsurprisingly with all the guess work).

Comment: user32, kernel32 are system dll's on most window machines (for example I have user32.dll in both "C:\Windows\System32" and "C:\Windows\SysWOW64".  I suspect that your error is due to the linker (note the ld) not being able to find the appropriate lib files.  Due a quick search for user32.lib and make sure that the linker can find it.  You may need to use the -L option to set the path.  If you do not have the *.lib files, you may need to add the MS Windows SDK (or try linking with the *.dll's).

Comment: That got it, I found the user32.dll in System32 and added it to my gcc line with `gcc pingpipe.c -o pingpipe -L C:\\Windows\\System32`. Thanks! Just curious but whats the relationship between "ld" and linkers?

Comment: did you run the script that sets up the environment, etc?  This needs to be done at each execution of `cygwin` (which is why executing the script needs to be added to the startup batch file used for starting `cygwin`

Comment: `ld` is the name of the linker utility

Comment: @thurizas, could you add an answer that contains your comment?  Then the OP can accept that answer, to close this question

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and the resolution was adding the Cygwin package `w32api-runtime`

Depending on what you are trying to do you may need `w32api-headers` too